# Click on a DIV to subscribe one of the RSS feeds

Tags: javascript, html, rss, onclick

I have several RSS feeds on one of my sites. My client asked me to place an RSS icon in the site so if you click on it, you can select which feed you want to subscribe on (the same action when you click on Safari's RSS icon in the Location Bar).

So, my  question is: how can I do that?

Here is a printscreen so you can see what I want to do.

[image: Multiple RSS Feeds]

Thanks a lot.

Comment: Try creating a hidden div with links to your feeds in it and display it when the user clicks on the RSS icon (using jquery for example).

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if this is the route you want to go.  Firefox removed the RSS icon from the location bar, so you may get inconsistent results within different browsers.

However, to do what you want, you just need to embed the following  tag:

```
<link rel="alternate" type="application/rss+xml" title="RSS Feed Title Goes Here" href="http://www.example.com/rss/rssfeed.xml" />
```

You can embed as many of these as you like.

EDIT:  "My client asked me to place an RSS icon in the site so if you click on it, you can select which feed you want to subscribe on"

For something like that, just create an icon on the site, with a dropdown menu appearing with links to the various feeds.  You can find numerous samples of dropdown menus through Google.

Comment: @peendraggon87, thank for the reply! Yes, I have multiple feed tags (for news, events and so on) and that's why I needed to select one of those feeds. Maybe it could be a solution if I place a dropdown. I hope my client will be just OK with that. (: